# AWS Pfsense OpenVPN no access to private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

My question is about not being able to connect to my private instance in `AWS VPC` through a `VPN`.

I have set up a `pfsense` instance that also acts as the `OpenVPN` server.

Then I installed `pfsense` on `AWS` with the official pfsense `AMI` and everything is working as expected so far.

I have 1 public subnet and 1 private subnet containing a linux instance that I want to reach via the `VPN`.

When connecting to the `VPN` I can't ping the linux instance in the private subnet.

The pfsense firewall (2.4.4) has the following interfaces:

```
**WAN** 10.3.0.245
**LAN** 10.3.1.5
```

The OpenVPN tunnel network is `10.3.2.0/24` going to `10.3.1.0/24` channeling all trafic trough the VPN.

The linux instance has the following private IP: `10.3.1.58`

The firewall itself can ping the instance and when I connect to the VPN (windows host) I can ping the firewall on `10.3.1.5` .

However, I can't ping `10.3.1.58` (request timed out).
I cant SSH either into the instance.

Could the route table be wrong? 
[image]

Route print on windows vpn client:
[image]

The security group in amazon allows all trafic for now.
Disabled the firewall on the linux system.
Disabled source / destination checking on the instance and the secondary network interface.

I have allowed traffic from the vpn to the lan (for now I allowed all traffic to see where the problem lies).

Comment: update; i can ping from the linux instance to the vpn assigned IP but not from the VPN client to the private subnet instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hosts have their gateway set as 10.3.1.1, it should be 10.3.1.5 (PFSense Lan).

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable source/destination checks on the pfsense instance?
You can disable it by following this guide - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck

Comment: Ýes I disabled source/desitnation checks on both the network interfaces.

Comment: update; i can ping from the linux instance to the vpn assigned IP but not from the VPN client to the private subnet instance

Comment: Ok, can you add a route pointing 10.3.2.0/24 to the pfsense LAN interface and check ?

Comment: How can I do that in pfsense? When going to System > routing > static routes add and fill in the destination network 10.3.2.0/24 there is only an option for the WAN gateway 10.3.0.1